# Failure Processing Application Bundle. Bundle header version compatibility check failed

Tags: c#, .net, azure-pipelines, publish

I've developed an C# ASP.NET application which runs successfully. I'm then publishing the application using the following publish command

dotnet publish MyApplication/MyApplication/MyApplication.csproj -c release --output Dll/MyApplication -r win-x86 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -p:DebugType=None -p:DebugSymbols=false -p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=*.pdb

The publish command successfully runs to completion and produces the expected files.
When I go to run the published .exe I get the following error message.

***Failure processing application bundle.
Bundle header version compatibility check failed. Header version: 538976266.572530720
A fatal error occurred while processing application bundle.***

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just curious if you made any headway on this?

Comment: Absolutely none at all, the above works fine for me with .net 5 but not .net 6. I'd love an answer

Comment: I ran into the same problem... sort of had a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76167641/how-to-resolve-bundle-header-version-compatibility-check-failed

Comment: I also turned off PublishSingleFile, which I'd a workaround, but it produces all of the files and doesn't condense them nicely as I hoped. I have .NET5 projects and they work fine with the above command. .NET6 however seems to be the one that has this problem.