# How to resolve "Bundle header version compatibility check failed"?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Had a user come up with an error during an install of our software informing them to install the .Net Desktop Runtime.  Did a "dotnet --list-runtimes" and saw that they had the latest for running a .Net6 application.  Looking in the event viewer it had this:

```
Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: Some.exe
Path: C:\.....\Some.exe
Message: Failure processing application bundle.
Bundle header version compatibility check failed.
A fatal error occured while processing application bundle
```

I searched and found this [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59819) issue.  It's closed, but the problem seems to still be happening. Unchecking "Produce single file" when publishing seems to fix the situation, however I am skeptical.

Is this still a known problem?  Any thoughts?  Is there a better resolution to this?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Dice No, although we believe it might have been a security/permissions issue.  Logging in as admin allowed them to install the software.

Comment: It's good to know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but we've had the same problem several days ago. Our project was developed on Net 6, the client's station had only Net 5, but instead of saying "Install Net 6, please", it was giving us this cryptic error. After we installed Net 6 error was gone.

Comment: We already had .NET6 installed on the servers as there were other .NET6 apps running.